# Error with Grails on Windows. unable to find valid certification

Tags: java, windows, grails, grails-2.0

I am trying to get grails working on windows for the first time.

I have:

```
| Grails Version: 3.0.2
| Groovy Version: 2.4.3
| JVM Version: 1.8.0_45
```

After doing the install if I goto a grails project and I run the following command

```
grails clean
```

I get the following error message

```
Error Error occurred running Grails CLI: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

I really dont use windows much so I really need details steps on how to address this issue.. please be details with how to fix it..

It would be great if you can post the step by steps commands to fix it..

Answer (score 1):

Check your local .m2 directory to see if you have a settings.xml file in there which may be pointing to an alternate repository.  This is what I ran into, because I was pointed at a repo that didn't have a signed certificate.